# ArrayBlockingQueue deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

So, I'm currently having a producer - consumer system that use `ArrayBlockingQueue`. 
All iz well for a long time, but yesterday the system is halting, and when I do `jstack` over the jvm, I found out that all threads that are supposed to "offer" is in `Thread.State: WAITING` when offering to the ArrayBlockingQueue, and all threads that are supposed to **"poll"** is also in `Thread.State: WAITING` condition when polling from `ArrayblockingQueue`.

I'm still new in analyzing jstack result, but from my understanding the log produced by jstack is a snapshot of all thread state in jvm. If so, I'm guessing this is a deadlock?

I've tried googling the cause, but can't seem to find anyone talking about deadlock in ArrayBlockingQueue. I also unable to reproduce the problem.
Are there any known issue for this particular problem?

this is some log generated by jstack:

offer:

```
ClientHandlerISO_404" prio=10 tid=0x8be5c800 nid=0x5299 waiting on condition [0x8b28c000..0x8b28ce30]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x95515440> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:747)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:778)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1971)
        at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.offer(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:287)
        at id.co.vsi.common.database.DB.insertToTableAsynchronously(DB.java:177)
```

poll:

```
DBQueryFileWriter_210" prio=10 tid=0x09528c00 nid=0x4eab waiting on condition [0x8cea1000..0x8cea1db0]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x95515440> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:747)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:778)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1971)
        at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:342)
        at id.co.vsi.common.database.DBQueryFileWriter.run(DBQueryFileWriter.java:164)
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: And you have a single unique `BlockingQueue` involved?

Comment: yes, you can't see it from the log, but both thread actually access single static ArrayBlockingQueue object.

Comment: A deadlock in a `BlockingQueue` would be a serious bug. I suppose you can't reproduce it?

Comment: That's the thing though, I can't. I still haven't figured out the common factor, any suggestion?

Comment: which java? is it possible related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292577/is-it-possible-for-concurrenthashmap-to-deadlock?rq=1