# Thread safe but does not prevent deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, class, deadlock

I came across this line which states that "However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access"in the overall description of Java class [ConcurrentHashMap] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). My question is: does this mean that the ConcurrentHasMap does not prevent dead lock? Also I thought being thread-safe imply no dead lock will take place?

Comment: Operations on  ConcurrentHashMap does not cause a deadlock - and hopefully noone would label a piece of code as thread safe if it could cause a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback and accept!

Comment: @nos: it’s not so easy. In Java 8, `ConcurrentHashMap` offers the `compute…` methods that allow to update a mapping while locking that specific key (or bucket), which implies that the provided function *must not* try to update another mapping during the evaluation (or try to acquire any other lock). So *correctly used*, a  `ConcurrentHashMap` will never cause a deadlock, but the possibility of a deadlock when being used incorrectly doesn’t imply that  `ConcurrentHashMap` is not thread safe…

Comment: interesting post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292577/is-it-possible-for-concurrenthashmap-to-deadlock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get things the wrong way: whenever you create a design that requires locking, you open up the *possibility* for dead locks.

That doesn't necessarily mean that any such architecture is per se vulnerable to dead-locks.

Example: a typical dead lock situation is when thread A has lock L1 and waits for lock L2; whereas thread B holds L2 and needs L1. If you only have **one** lock object, then that scenario is one .. that can't happen.

In other words: you are not using class X it would *prevent* deadlocks. That is not possible. If at all, you might be using class X because it offers you functionality that allows you to come up with a "guaranteed-dead-lock-free" design!

Answer (score 5):

A deadlock can occur only when there *are* two different locks, i.e. when you are holding a lock and waiting for another lock to release. (There are more conditions on deadlocks, however).

As the ConcurrentHashMap tries to *avoid* locks where possible, you are not able to acquire a lock with operations *only* on the map that the map may wait for.
Hence, operations only on the map do not cause deadlocks.

---

However, *thread-safety* does not mean *deadlock free*. It only guarantees that the code will operate according to its interface, *even* when called from multiple threads.
Making a class thread-safe usually includes *adding* locks to guarantee safe execution.

You may also want to have a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Comment: Nice answer too; and actually not so much different from mine. Lets honor that.